# Getting undefined reference errors in c compiling via gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, undefined-reference

Already fixed it thx

I got 5 files:
cdouble.c cdouble.h cmatrix.c cmatrix.h and main.c

in my cdouble.c I have:

```
#include "cdouble.h"
```

in my cmatrix.c I have:

```
#include "cmatrix.h"
```

(in my cmatrix.h file i got: `#include "cdouble.h"`

And in my main file I have:

```
#include "cmatrix.h"
```

I need to compile it on my university's unix(?) server.
I tried:

```
gcc -c cmatrix.c
gcc cmatrix.o main.c
```

but I got many "undefined reference errors"

> $ gcc -c cmatrix.c
>
> gcc cmatrix.o main.c:
>   /tmp/ccZD6esL.o: In function `ishermitian`:
>   main.c:(.text+0x7b): undefined reference to `cConj`
>   main.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `getCDoubleImag`
>   main.c:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `getCDoubleReal`
>   main.c:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `getCDoubleImag`
>   main.c:(.text+0xef): undefined reference to `getCDoubleImag`
>   main.c:(.text+0x111): undefined reference to `getCDoubleReal`
>   main.c:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `getCDoubleReal`
>   /tmp/ccZD6esL.o: In function `scancdouble`:
>   main.c:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `newCDouble`
>   /tmp/ccZD6esL.o: In function `main`:
>   main.c:(.text+0x2d8): undefined reference to `getCDoubleImag`
>   main.c:(.text+0x2fc): undefined reference to `getCDoubleReal`
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: *What* are those "undefined reference errors"? When posting questions about build errors, always copy (as text) the full and complete output, and paste it into the body of the question.

Comment: A hint though: When and where do you build with `cdouble.c` (or its object file)?

Comment: You really need to add those error messages. There's no way for us to know.

Comment: posted the error messages

Comment: Could already fix it, thx

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile cdouble.c and link its .o file as well. E.g:

```
gcc -c cmatrix.c
gcc -c cdouble.c
gcc main.c cmatrix.o cdouble.o
```

or, more simply:

```
gcc main.c cmatrix.c cdouble.c
```